# Switched to new router and now experiencing lag?

Tags: internet, wireless-router, ps3, lag

I switched from a dynex-802.11b/g to a Netgear-802.11b/g/n just yesterday. My router is down stairs because my phoneline upstairs is retarded....but my PS3 is still upstairs (SOCOM: Confrontation is game I am experiencing issues). I have done everything I can to make sure the connection is solid and have checked the status and it has been as high as 80% and usually lingers at about 60%. I thought about upgrading my bandwidth from 1.5mbs to 7mbs, but I am guessing something is wrong if it worked fine before? Now the game seems more laggy and my voice chat is choppy. Others seem to receive my voice data fine because I can hear my own feedback clearly from other players (if you are in close proximity to another player and speak and there volume is loud enough sometimes you can hear yourself). I wonder if I port forward or setup DMZ then it will be fixed, but I am not sure and don't know quite how to do it. Has anyone else ever experienced this when switching routers? What did you do to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the account, possible is a problem with the Netgear router. 
1.5 Mb is fine if there is no somebody a lot of bandwidth at the same time. 
You could try to put your console in the DMZ, usually is a very simple operation, you just have to chose your console IP or MAC Address and the routers do the rest.

you can try also, just for checking, using a cable to connect your console directly.

Comment: Thanks, I just enabled DMZ on my router, encrypted the connection and more importantly: updated the firmware. I don't have time to test my ps3 connection out right now, but I will try and post if it worked later.